# XSLT 2.0 xsl:result-document every n elements

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a XML as follows:

```
<list>
<element>1</element>
<element>2</element>
<element>3</element>
<element>4</element>
<element>5</element>
<element>6</element>
<element>7</element>
<element>8</element>
<element>9</element>
<element>10</element>
<element>11</element>
<element>12</element>
<element>13</element>
<element>14</element>
<element>15</element>
<element>16</element>
<element>17</element>
<element>18</element>
<element>19</element>
<element>20</element>
```

Then I use this template to write the content to a file

```
<xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:result-document href="file:///c:/temp/bic.txt">
            <xsl:for-each select="element"> 
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

But now I want to split the output so each five elements go to a different file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use positional grouping:

```
<xsl:template match="list">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="element" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 5">
    <xsl:result-document href="bic-{position()}.txt" method="text">
      <xsl:value-of select="current-group()" separator=""/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```